# Visualización de datos de tabla access en c#

Tags: c#, ms-access

Tengo una conexión entre access y visual studio y utilizo este código para la conexión.

`conexion.ConnectionString = ("provider=microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;data source=" & " C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\PROGRAMACION\VB\LoginDefinitivo\Usuarios.accdb")
conexion.Open()`

Que código podría utilizar para mostrar los datos de la tabla tipo access

Comment: ¿Y qué le ocurre a tu código? ¿Da algún error?

Answer (score 1):

Utilizas un dataset o un datatable que llenas con un dataadapter, y luego usas un Datagridview para mostrarlos.

```
using (var adap = new OledbDataAdapter()){
   using (var comm = new Oledbcommand()){
      comm.CommandText = "tu query";
      adap.selectcommand = comm;
      using (var dset = new Dataset()){
         adap.fill(dset,'tu tabla');
         /*
          *    Llenas tu grid View usando de data Source 
          *    Dataset y de datamember
          *    Un string con el nombre de tu tabla.
          */
         this.Datagridview.DataSource=dset;
         this.Datagridview.Datamember="tu tabla";
}
}
}
```